# Linking within the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have seen a lot of websites where they are [linking in the same page](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_link_locations).
[(demo)](http://jsbin.com/batafetu/1/edit)
The problem in this system is, when you reload the page after clicking the link (which refers you to the selected area), the page immediately scrolled to the selected area, because the click on the link leaves a `#name` on the URL page (even when reloading), for example:

> www.example.com/#down

I have seen also websites, where they don't add `#name` to the URL line but you still referred to the linked area.
I guessed this has been made by jQuery or Javascript but I couldn't find (inspect element and page's source) the code (I found this system in high-tech sites, where they have a lot of js files and it was complicated to find).

**My  real question is: how can I link within my website, without using the** *hash-tag|name* **system?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behaviour you describe is the intended, desired behaviour of anchors. As [has been said](http://motherfuckingwebsite.com/)...

> Websites aren't broken by default, they are functional, high-performing, and accessible. You break them.

You can have an event listener detect clicks on links and scroll accordingly. jQuery would be something like this:

```
$(document).on("click", "a[href*='#']", function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    var target = this.href.split("#")[1];
    var elm = document.getElementById(target);
    if( elm) elm.scrollIntoView(); // or replace with fancy scrollTo plugin
});
```

However, be aware that doing this *decreases usability*. From xkcd...

[image: xkcd]

Comment: you forgot the preventDefault()

Comment: it's a relief to know that I'm not the only one who realized that parallax and infinite scrolling are not useful at all and are _anti-usability_ instead

Comment: @Ejay I have gotten angry at the designer sitting opposite me on more than one occasion...

Answer (score 0):

[Working DEMO](http://jsbin.com/batafetu/2/edit)

HTML:

```
  <a href="#demo">GO SEE THE DEMO</a>
```

jQuery:

```
$("a").click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var divId = $(this).attr('href');
  $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(divId).offset().top 
        }, 500);
});
```